# Failed without error message: mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf when creating pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

We are using use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf for genrating pdf where we are having some javascript to generate pdf. We have created command where it create the pdf but ehen i am running the command it states the error as below. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
Failed without error message: wkhtmltopdf "--enable-javascript" "1" "--javascript-delay" "5000" "--enable-smart-shrinking" "1" "--no-stop-slow-scripts" "1" "C:\Users\santosh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2BA5.tmp.html" "C:\Users\santosh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2BA6.tmp.pdf" (Exit code: 1)
```

The command of laravel is as below:

```
public function handle()
    {
        try{
            $vd['data'] = $data;
            $render = view('reports.email-triggers.reportData')->with(compact('vd'));

            $pdf = new Pdf;
            $pdf->addPage($render);
            $pdf->setOptions(['enable-javascript' => true]);
            $pdf->setOptions(['javascript-delay' => 15000]);
            $pdf->setOptions(['enable-smart-shrinking' => true]);
            $pdf->setOptions(['no-stop-slow-scripts' => true]);
            $pdf->setOptions(['javascript-delay' => 5000]);
            if(!$pdf->saveAs('report.pdf')){
                dd($pdf->getError());
            }    
            $pdf->download('C:\xampp\htdocs\serviceticketflow\itm-encode\dem.pdf');
        }catch(Exception $e){
            dd($e);
            Log::error('EmailReportTrigger-command () : '.$e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Remove brackets. This is right syntax: $pdf->setOptions('enable-javascript' => true);

Comment: it wont work as enable options take array